# How to catch the line that emitted signal in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Code below is part of my program:

```
connect(dockObject, &QDockWidget::visibilityChanged, 
        [=](bool visible)
        {
            qDebug() << "Visibility:" << visible;
        });
dockObject->setVisible(false); // this line changed visibility so the visibilityChanged signal was emitted
```

And here is the terminal outputs:

> Visibility: false 
> Visibility: true

Now my problem is : `Visibility: true` indicates that visibility of `dockObject` changed somewhere I don't know. I want to know which line changed it, is it possible?

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to put `qDebug()` statement every where in your code just before calling `setVisible()` and check the output.

Comment: Maybe, you can set a breakpoint in your lambda, so that debugging stops there. Then you should be able to see the caller on the callstack. That won't work for events (where the sender is always the event loop) but for signals with direct connection, it should work.